# How is quadratic form of miller index useful?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, x-ray-crystallography

I have seen that we have used the $h^2+k^2+l^2$ value for finding whether the lattice is BCC,FCC or simple cubic.Where is this factor coming from?Why can I not use the structure factor theorem expression for this?

Comment: This is really just geometry. The spacing of lattice planes (the $d$ in Bragg's law $\lambda = 2d\sin(\theta)$) depends on the factor you quote, thus its important in x-ray diffraction experiments. What part of the geometry is confusing to you?

Comment: Why are we using $h^2+k^2+l^2$ sometimes and a different form for hexagonal.Where does the intuition of the formula come from?